# how can I start up an object in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

.exe does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for entry point.

For this purpose, I  have gone to to my project properties on the application tab and then start up object but it showed me that it wasn't set and I cannot enter my program like frmMain.

How can I enter my program on the startup object?

Comment: I THINK YOU NEED A MAIN METHOD

Comment: HAOLADER, your caps-lock key is located approximately 1/3 inch to the left of your `A` key.

Answer (score 4):

Create a new source code file (perhaps name it "Program.cs"). Inside that file, insert something like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace MyApplication
{
     class Program
     {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
            Console.WriteLine("* Press Any Key to Exit *");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
     }
}
```